# Ground wires crimped in copper sleeves in switch box?

Tags: electrical, wiring, switch, grounding

I had to move a two-gang switch box to a new location on my wall. This meant disassembling everything, moving the box, and reassembling it as I found it.

The only thing that seems a bit sketchy is how the ground wires are connected together.

The three ground wires coming into the box are crimped together with a copper sleeve. One wire continues through and is connected to the ground screw of one of the two switches. This wire is folded midway between the crimp and the ground screw. The fold is twisted with a pigtail that connects to the ground screw of the second switch, and the twist is capped with a wire nut.

[image: crimp closeup]
[image: grounding assembly]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Code allows the crimp sleeves for grounds. The proper procedure is to tie all grounds in the box together with a crimp sleeve or green wire nut, then from there run an individual 'pigtail' conductor to the switch or outlet, continuing the unbroken single conductor to all other switches or outlets in that box.

Phil

Comment: Thanks. So, given the description and photos, this seems to be a code-compliant/safe setup for the grounding?

Comment: @Steven, very much so.